# How to plot the ACF of each column of the matrix in the same plot in R

Tags: r, plot, autocorrelation

I Simulated 10 realisations with 200 observations from an MA(3) process and plot them. The code I used is the following and the result in the picture:

[image]

Now I want to estimate the autocorrelation function (ACF) for each realisation and plot those in the same plot as seen below:

[image]

I want to plot them like this by creating lines of different colours by joining the points ... not the classical ACF plot with the spikes. I tried some things but I cannot figure out how to do it. Any help please?

The code I used for the first part (I am working with R in RStudio):

```
sim1 <- replicate(10,arima.sim(model = list(ma=c(0.7,-0.7,-0.4), order=c(0,0,3)), n = 200))
matplot(sim1, lty=1, type="l", col=rainbow(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this without using `ggplot2`, so here it is:

First, some adaptations. I decreased the number of simulations to 3, so it's easier to understand the graphs; I added an `Time` column to serve as the x-axis; I Created the ACF for each simulation with `apply`, and stored it in a new df; And i pivoted the data to long for use of `ggplot`:

```
sim1 <- cbind("Time"=1:200, replicate(3,arima.sim(model = list(ma=c(0.7,-0.7,-0.4), order=c(0,0,3)), n = 200)))
acfsim1 <- cbind("Lag"=1:200, apply(sim1[,2:4], 2, function(x){acf(x, 200, plot=FALSE)$acf}))

dfsim1 = tidyr::pivot_longer(as.data.frame(sim1), cols=2:4)
dfacfsim1 = tidyr::pivot_longer(as.data.frame(acfsim1), cols=2:4)
```

Now for the plots. First the one you already had:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dfsim1, aes(y=value, color=name, x=Time)) +
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Now the graph that you want, first using a line graph:

```
ggplot(dfsim1, aes(y=value, color=name, x=Lag)) +
  geom_segment(data=dfacfsim1)
```

Output:

[image]

Now with a segment graph:

```
ggplot(dfsim1, aes(y=value, color=name, x=Lag)) +
  geom_segment(data=dfacfsim1, aes(xend=Lag, yend=0))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend! Everything runs fine, however in the exact point that I specifically need (the acf line plot) when I run the line of code you wrote the following error occours "geom_segment requires the following missing aesthetics: xend and yend" . Everything else runs fine (I made it for 10 realisations ) including the acf with the spikes. How can I fix this error to take your outcome?

Comment: You're welcome! Oh sorry, do `geom_segment(data=dfacfsim1, aes(xend=Lag, yend=0))`

Comment: I did that but that gives the last outcome with the spikes.  Anyway ... I tried ggplot(dfacfsim1, aes(y=value, color=name, x=Lag)) + geom_line()  and it seems that worked so that's fine. The thing is that I have to do the same for the partial autocorellation but it doesnt work. I added to this code the ACF part of the code replacing "acf" with "pacf" but something seems to be very wrong ... If you can help me with that too I would be really really greatfull!!!!

Comment: I didn't understood your problem with the spikes then. As for the pacf, i actually found that `acf` by default calculates the correlation (do `?acf`) so we need to do: `acfsim1 <- cbind("Lag"=1:200, apply(sim1[,2:4], 2, function(x){acf(x, 200, "covariance", FALSE)$acf}))` for the ACF, and 
`pacfsim1 <- cbind("Lag"=1:200, apply(sim1[,2:4], 2, function(x){acf(x, 200, "correlation", FALSE)$acf}))` for the PACF. The rest of the code is the same for the PACF.

Comment: But in the code you sent me you although you change the name of the value you use again the acf function. If you change the acf with pacf the code doesnt run. At least that happened to me when I tried that. Does it run to you? Can you get the plots of the partial auto correlations?

Comment: Yeah i made a mistake, `acf` set to `"correlation"` and `"covariance"` are both ACF, you indeed need to use `pacf`. The problem is that `pacf` doesn't return the lag 0, so that's why the graph looks weird. As the PACF for lag 0 is always 1, you can do: `pacfsim1 <- cbind("Lag"=1:200, apply(sim1[,2:4], 2, function(x){c(1,pacf(x,200,FALSE)$acf}))`. If the thing about the lag 0 wasn't what went wrong with your code, can you explain better what happened?

Comment: For sure ... Well the problem still exists. This line of code(the one you sent me) runs perfectly. As it happened before. However, it is created a matrix with two coloumns instead of eleven (or four in the 3 different scenario example - in the code of your original answer check the acfsim1 - it has 200 rows and 4 coloumns) now the pacfsim1 has only two coloumns: one with lags and one full of 1. So when I try to continoue with the next line (dfpacfsim1 = tidyr::pivot_longer(as.data.frame(pacfsim1), cols=2:11) ) the error is: "can´t subset columns that dont exist. x locations 3,4... dont exist"

Comment: Well ... i found it so i leave it here as feedback: pacfsim1 <- cbind("Lag"=1:25, apply(sim1[1:25,2:11], 2,function(x){pacf(sim1[,2], lag.max  = 25, plot = FALSE)$acf}))